# NumLock is completely useless, and I want to disable it completely on Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, gnome, keyboard-layout, xorg

Forget all the rants about <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> is the most useless key of them all. It's never, ever useful. You don't want to use your numpad as an arrowpad, since the arrows are 1cm away from it. Ever.

There was a time when some keyboards had a numpad but no dedicated arrow keys. They don't exist anymore. You can find keyboards with no numpad but with arrow keys, but not the opposite.

Therefore, <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> is useless, and it only serves to aggravate me and, I presume, others. Please note that I do *not* want to know how to turn <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> on at startup, I do not want to know how to tear the key off, I want to disable it so that it stays on all the time and can't be turned off by mistake. Any idea how to do that?

Ideally I'd like to be able to reclaim the key for another use, such as a modifier that allows me to type hex on the numpad.

Additionally I'd love to know how to turn off the equally useless mouse emulation triggered by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Num Lock</kbd>.

Comment: And how do you get the nice key cap style in MarkDown? Couldn't find it!

Comment: It's <kbd></kbd>

Comment: The <kbd> tag is not a feature of MarkDown!  It has been around since HTML 3.2.

Comment: +1 I admire your passion, it reflects my feelings on CapsLock vs Ctrl.

Comment: low tech solution: lever the key off the keyboard

Comment: @rich: I said I didn't want to hear about that, and it doesn't solve the problem, since if for some reason numlock turns off, you can't turn it back on.

Comment: I'd advise editing out the rant; there are inevitably some uses that your experience doesn't come across, such as uses that Mad Fish pointed out. From the FAQ:  Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!

Comment: @Kevin: and what are those uses? I haven't found one in the last 20 years.

Comment: My laptop has Home, End, PageUp and PageDown on num keys, the alternative versions of these keys are much harder to reach or need a modifier key. I need these a lot more than the numbers. For me I would disable NumLock key and _never_ have numbers. I wonder if that can be done.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well for your first question, you can remap it to nothing with `xmodmap`:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode # = """
```

where # is the scan code of NumLock. You can find the scan code using `xev`. Instead of nothing you can remap it to any key you'd like.

Comment: Well thank you very much, that answered my question. I did `xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = ISO_Level3_Shift Num_Lock'`, so that I can turn the thing on if it goes off, and use the key itself as a modifier.

Comment: Nice idea, well done :)

Comment: This has worked for me for more than a few years: `xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = NoSymbol'`

Answer (score 4):

**For Ubuntu 16.04** - `xmodmap` is not a permanent solution. Instead, install "Gnome Tweak Tools", navigate to Typing-->Miscellaneous Compatibility Options, and select "Numeric keypad keys always enter digits".

Comment: Same for Fedora

Comment: Works great for Ubuntu 18.04. I found the option under "Keyboard & Mouse" -- "Additional Layout Options" -- "Miscellaneous Compatibility Options"

Answer (score 3):

I noticed this was tagged "Gnome", however for those who ended up here and are using KDE, it is really easy to make the numpad always print numbers.

In System settings > Hardware > Input devices > Keyboard > Advanced

Check "Configure keyboard options"
then check "Miscellanous compatibilty options" > "Numeric keypad always enter digits (as in Mac OS)"

Click apply and it works directly.

"Miscellanous compatibilty options" > "Toggle PonterKeys with Shift + NumLock"
Will turn on/off mouse emulation by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>NumLock</kbd>, however this is off by default.

Comment: Works for me: on Linux Mint 18.2: Keyboard > Layouts > Options... > "Miscellanous compatibilty options" > "Numeric keypad always enter digits (as in Mac OS)"

Comment: I've noticed that for 25% of all my applications the numeric keys on the keypad behave always as if num lock is off. KDevelop and Cura have their num lock behavior inverted after the above fix.

Answer (score 2):

For further reading, check out the [`loadkeys`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/loadkeys.1.html) command, it can alter the keyboard for console logins, too.

Answer (score 2):

Well I know for sure that if you run this as root, it will enable Num Lock, and at least on my machine I cannot turn it off,

```
echo /etc/rc.local >> 'for tty in /dev/tty?; do /usr/bin/setleds -D +num < "$tty"; done'
```

I am using Arch Linux, so you might want to find the appropriate file for your particular flavour of *nix... but this should enable Num Lock at boot, and leave the actual key open to be remapped. I love the idea of using it as a modifer to type in Hex, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

Following John and niXar's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/71634/100736) above, for a standard keyboard, this should be added to your `.xprofile` or a similar file:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = NoSymbol Num_Lock'
```

Explanation:

- [`xmodmap`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.2/doc/xmodmap.1.html) is a "utility for modifying keymaps and pointer button mappings in Xorg".
- `-e` evaluates a `xmodmap` command.
- `keycode` is a command to assign `keycode`s (physical keys) to `keysym`s ("encoding of a symbol on the cap of a key", see below.)
- Keycode 77 is the `NumLock` key.
- The first keysym, `NoSymbol` is the key press output when no modifiers are pressed with this key.
- The second keysym, `Num_Lock` is the key press output when the shift modifier is pressed with this key.