# How do I disable Num Lock in Linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, xorg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NumLock is completely useless, and I want to disable it completely on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/71630/numlock-is-completely-useless-and-i-want-to-disable-it-completely-on-linux)

On an Apple keyboard there is no Num Lock. The numeric keypad is always *numeric*, not a useless set of arrow and paging keys.

How do I configure my Linux keyboard layout so Num Lock is a no-op and the numeric keypad always produces numbers?

Comment: Duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/71630/numlock-is-completely-useless-and-i-want-to-disable-it-completely-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

[xmodmap](http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/xmodmap.1.html) is your friend here:

> The xmodmap program is used to edit and display the keyboard modifier
>   map and keymap table that are used by client applications to convert
>   event keycodes into keysyms. It is usually run from the user's session
>   startup script to configure the keyboard according to personal tastes.